# Set a visible value and a hidden value to JQuery UI's autocomplete

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui

I'd like to know if there's any way to set an autocomplete array with multiple allotted values?

For example, to use the classic example of programming languages, if someone types "Java Script" I'd like for "Javascript" to show up, is there any way to do this?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by 'multiple allotted values'?

Comment: My next sentence should explain it perfectly; ie: let people type "javascript" or "java script" to get the suggestion of "javascript"

Comment: part of it can be done easily using bootstrap typeahead. but when you type "java script" completely then it won't show "javascript" because a black space is there..check this http://www.bootply.com/ljIOxm3qDi out.

Comment: thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

This ain't really an efficient fix to your problem, but if the cases are few then you can use it as a temporary fix.

So basically instead of providing a simple **array of strings** as source to your autocomplete, you can provide the source with an **array of objects which has key value pairs**.

See the official documentation here -> http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

```
some_array = [{label:'Java Script', value:'Javascript'}, {label:'JS', value:'Javascript'}, {label:'java_script', value:'Javascript'}]
```

This way **all the three options** will be displayed initially, which I feel is technically incorrect. But if the user quickly types in '**JS**' or '**Java Script**' in the input field as you mentioned is the case, then Javascript won't be amongst the autocomplete suggestions.

Using the above, all three will be available in the suggestions, but irrespective of what the user selects out of those three, the input value of the field will go as 'Javascript'.

But as I said, it's an inefficient fix to your problem.

Comment: yeah. I was thinking of maybe doing something like this. but you know what, the user can deal with it. if they wanna use different delimiters, the search will still work, they just wont get a drop-down

Comment: Ya, but it's more about how you see the problem from backend point of view. The search will work in any case, its just that you'll have to do cleaning of the submitted form data at the backend, like trimming whitespaces or other delimiters as well if you only want to allow one specific value for Javascript in your database. Choice is yours where you want to handle it, at the backend or at the frontend. That's it. :)

Comment: I think the route I'm going to go down is, give them a list of suggestions, and if they decide not to pick out of those and type in their own search, they wont get suggestions, but the search will work. It'll be good enough.

Thanks a lot!